# Get specific items from partition which should not be in other partition

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I have below table -

`ID   type  group_name  creation_date
    1    A       G1           C1
    2    B       G2           C2
    3    C       G2           C3
    4    B       G1           C4`

I want to extract the old type items in each group, but if that type item is latest item in other partition , then i won't extract that.

So, for G1, I will have 2 items A and B where C1 > C4
For G2, I  will have 2 items B and C where C2 > C3.

Ideally, B is older for group G1 and C is older for group G2

But i don't want to extract B for G1 since it is latest for G2. Hence 
the output should be C only.

Could anyone help how can i achieve this ?

Comment: What happens if you have rows `5,D,G3,C5` and `6,D,G4,C5` (same type and creation date but different group names and ids)?

Comment: For each group , i want to extract all items except the latest one. If i have 2 more rows having group G3 and G4, then i won't extract them since both of them are latest for their own group

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       type
FROM   (
  SELECT type,
         rnk,
         COUNT( CASE rnk WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY type ) AS ct
  FROM   (
    SELECT type,
           RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY creation_date DESC ) AS rnk
     FROM  table_name
  )
)
WHERE  rnk > 1 AND ct = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
TYPE
----
C
```